# How to compare the diff between two branches, excluding rebase commit

Tags: git, gerrit

Background：

I have developed a code review platform that was inspired by the design of Gerrit.

In this platform, there is a concept of "revision," which can have multiple "patchsets." Each patchset consists of several commits.

When viewing the diff between the base and a patchset, we use the command `git diff merge-base...HEAD`

Comparing patchsets is straightforward when the user hasn't performed a rebase on the patchset. In such cases, we can use the shadow branches of the two patchsets for the git diff.

However, when a user performs a rebase on the patchset against the master branch, the results are not as expected.

Currently, the git version used in the code review platform does not support the `git range-diff` command.

[image: branch commit info]

As pic,I want get the diff of patchset2...patchset3  excluding commit-e.

patchset3 may not only have commit-f

And the content of commit-d’ may not be equivalent to commit-d

what should I do？

use `git diff d f`   But the result is not as expected

thanks

Comment: do a `checkout --detach`, revert the commits you want to _not_ include in the diff and then do the diff against this.

Comment: Thx。 When there are a large number of rebase commits, will this operation be more cumbersome?

Answer (score 0):

In the given picture, the command would be

```
git range-diff d...f
```

or

```
git range-diff B d f
```

[(Manual page)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff). It may not be quite trivial to read the command's output when the rebased commits underwent conflict resolutions, but it is not rocket science, either.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will try upgrading the git version locally and see if it helps.